# Apply a random generator based on percentage values

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a spreadsheet with 7 thousands player stats from Pro Evolution Soccer and i wanna get the percentage of incidence of each value of each attribute based on his position.

Something like:

```
Striker - Attack = 99: 1.3%; 98: 1.8%; 97: 3.5%;...

CenterBack - Attack = 99: 0.002%; 98: 0.003%; 97: 0.006%;...
```

Then I will create a random player generator based on this parameters.

- So my problem is, how can i have this incidence?
- I think this is a machine learning application, am i wrong?
- Then, with this parameters, there is a way to generate something random but with percentage probability?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more please?

Comment: maybe frequency tables http://hamelg.blogspot.com/2015/11/python-for-data-analysis-part-19_17.html and this link https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_discrete.html are relevant?

Comment: What means `99`, `98`, `97`? Values of .. what? Power of strike? Probability of goal? A little more of soccer domain knowledge will be good for clarification

Comment: can you post any code attemp?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question directly: when you want to know percentiles of a certain distribution you can use numpy

```
import numpy as np
strikerAttackValueList=np.random.randint(0,100,1000)#example of stats list    
percentile50=np.percentile(strikerAttackValueList,50)
```

But this is as much a math statistics question as a coding question.

First step would be to check how the values in Pro Evolution Soccer are distributed. This could be normal, uniform,.. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions ) with a certain average and standard deviation. 
To know that, import the stat you want to study and do something like this: http://www.insightsbot.com/blog/WEjdW/fitting-probability-distributions-with-python-part-1

Then, to generate random player stats you can use either random or numpy (example assuming uniform distribution between 0 and 100):

```
import random
strikerAttackValue=random.randint(0,100)
print(strikerAttackValue)

import numpy as np
strikerAttackValue=np.random.randint(0,100)
print(strikerAttackValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [np.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) does the trick if you want to sample directly:

```
import numpy as np

# generate some stats (ie your soccer values)
np.random.seed(1)
soccer_stats = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=100)

# sample from them
sampled_stat = np.random.choice(soccer_stats)
print(sampled_stat)
```

> -0.8452056414987196

give a look at [np.histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) to observe the distribution you're sampling from.  [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is nice for looking at the distribution of non numerical data (maybe your soccer players names?)